# Flexbox template for a draggable list

Tags: list, templates, flexbox

I have a list of draggable items, for a responsive design :

https://codepen.io/daedrias/pen/KyPZYG

```css
header,
footer {
  background-color: #5fba7d;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 800px;
}

.menu {
  width: 15em;
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #958C4D;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.sortable-list {
  width: 18.75em;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row>* {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
  height: 2em;
  display: flex;
  cursor: move;
}

.handle {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.125em;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.icon {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #c97777;
  margin: 0 0.125em;
}

.stretch {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 0 0.1em;
}

.trash {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0.125em;
}

.bouton-ajout {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 0 2.2em 0 1.75em;
}


/* mobile layout */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .sortable-list {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>asdasd</p>

      <div class="sortable-list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="left">
            <div class="handle">=</div>
            <div class="icon"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="stretch">
            banana
          </div>
          <div class="trash">X</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="left">
            <div class="handle">=</div>
            <div class="icon"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="stretch">
            pineapple
          </div>
          <div class="trash">X</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="left">
            <div class="handle">=</div>
            <div class="icon"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="stretch">
            orange
          </div>
          <div class="trash">X</div>
        </div>

        <div class="bouton-ajout">
          + Add a row V
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div>
</body>
<html>
```

Everything is pretty much as I want it to be (as in : the positioning, not the colors of this example), but I'm not happy about the 'add' button.

I would like to know if there is a better way to handle the width of the 'Add'  button,so it is the same size as the icon + label combined. For now I use margins.

Is the flex display a good solution in this case? Should I use something else like display : table?

Comment: No, there is no better way as you use fixed width's on `row` items. To add Flexbox for that will take much more markup and CSS, as you need to copy a `.row`'s all markup, replace the `stretch` with your `button`, set the height on the `left`/`trash` to 0, add overflow (or delete the `=` and `X` in markup) and set the `icon` width to 0. .... so comparing with the margin, I choose margin 8 days per week :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the confirmation!